# MongoDB Scalable setup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scaling

Hello every i already setup this.

1. MongoDB Replica Sets with 3 members.
2. Enable indexing
3. Enable Oplog on my node.js app

I would like to ask other tips/guides how to optimize my mongodb.
It is good way to add Members in Replica set? or add a sharding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication is about durability and availability, not scaling. If you need to scale use sharding. Before setting up a sharded cluster several important decision should be made based on how your application operates (data model, most often requests etc.), for further reference see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#considerations-before-sharding).

Comment: In sharding, there's any easy configuration that all collection must be sharded?

Comment: I haven't heard of any.